# Match Datetime not showing results

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

```
$link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fashion",'root','');
$stmt=$link->prepare("select * from stylestatement where id='".$_REQUEST["you"]."'");
    if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['title']))) {
        $row=$stmt->fetch();
        $newstmt=$link->prepare("select * from images where `statementid`='".$_REQUEST["you"]."' and `added_on`='".$row["created_on"]."'");
        $newstmt->execute();
        echo($newstmt->rowCount());
    }
```

in the above code ,i get result= 0  even though i have the same datetime in images table, why?

Comment: if the field is datetime, make sure it match to very seconds in time. if there is a difference in even second it won't match.

Comment: it is same sir, thats why i am asking the question

Comment: remove the and condition and try in the query ...

Comment: `$newstmt=$link->prepare("select * from images where statementid=".$_REQUEST["you"]." and added_on='".$row["created_on"]."'");` remove the single inverted for `$_REQUEST["you"]` and the backticks also

Comment: i know this is not the solution but still :)

Comment: you are write, this is not the solution

Comment: can you echo out the query and use that query and run directly on DB, if it gives result or not. Sometime, we feel what we wrote is write, but runnig directly on db show use few error.

Comment: @user2889070 Try to replace your query as updated in my answer.

Comment: @SumitGupta you are great

Comment: so you solve it, I am happy about it, thanks.

Comment: @SumitGupta i can't vote up as i don't have points to vote up , as soon as i get points i will vote up your comments.

Comment: nevermind dude, if I need point I put it as answer :)...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **date method** for comparing the date with the database. so in your where condition use **date(`added_on`)** instead of **`added_on`** that will match the date.

Replace

```
$newstmt=$link->prepare("select * from images where `statementid`='".$_REQUEST["you"]."' and `added_on`='".$row["created_on"]."'");
```

To

```
$newstmt=$link->prepare("select * from images where `statementid`='".$_REQUEST["you"]."' and date(`added_on`)='".$row["created_on"]."'");
```

Comment: Care to mention the changes?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky i'm not getting you what you wanna say. i have updated query as per OP's requirement.

Comment: What have you fixed? Mentioning that will make it a good answer. Its not like OP should just copy paste your answer without knowing the fix

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky oh ya got it what you want to convey me. just going to update my answer thanks for tips.

Comment: what if i want to match time as well